# Counting, Indistinguishable

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An elevator starts at the basement with 8 people (not including the operator) and
discharges them all by the time it reaches the sixth floor. The operator has prosopagnosia,
which means that he is unable to tell people apart. In how many apparent ways
could have people left the elevator? (No one leaves in basement and people can exit on sixth floor. Operator does not leave.)

I have tried to think of it as *K* number of people=8 and *N* number of floors=6. 
The total different arrangements is ${N+K-1\choose N-1}$ which equals ${13 \choose 5}$ = 1287. 
I thought it as you have K objects, N slots to fill but only N-1 decisions to make. Does this sound good?

Comment: The above problem is the same as finding all possible non-negative integral solutions of the eqn. x + y + z + w + v + q = 8......and you can find this by using multinomial theorem.....I think your method is correct since it yields the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and it was correct.